# node.js module exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

What's the reason that this works:

```
exports.foo = 'foo';

var bar = require('./foo');
console.log(bar); // {foo: 'foo'}
```

but this doesn't:

```
var data = { foo: 'foo' };
exports = data;

var bar = require('./foo');
console.log(bar); // {}
// expected {foo: 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll Try to answer this as a javascript question
Code Sample

```
function a() {}
a.prototype.foo = {test:"bar"}
var d = new a();
var c = new a();
console.log(d.prototype ==== c.prototype) // Both c and d share the same prototype object
d.foo.hai = "hello"
console.log(d.prototype ==== c.prototype) // Still the they refer to the same
d.foo = {im: "sorry"}
console.log(d.prototype ==== c.prototype) // now they don't
```

The same for node

```
console.log(module.exports === exports);// true; They refer to the same object
exports.a = {tamil: "selvan"} 
console.log(module.exports === exports);// true even now 

exports = {sorry: "im leaving"}; // overrides modules.exports
console.log(module.exports === exports); //false now they don't
console.log(module.exports); // {a: {tamil: "selvan"}}
console.log(exports);  // {sorry: "im leaving"}
```

exports and module.exports refer to the same core object until you override as in javsacript prototype object. The moment you override the reference changes.

`module.exports = {something: "works"}` 
 works because you are changing the property of module that node cares while caching it.

Even for the above

`module.exports === exports //is false they are no more the same`

this proves that vice versa is also true :)

One more thing `module` is the reference to the current module so always prefer using `module.exports` than `exports`

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the second code by replacing `exports = data;` with `module.exports = data;`.

The reason the former doesn't work is that it only assigns to `exports` another object in the module name space. While the latter replaces the value of `exports` property on the `module` object with your `data` object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the second code you are basically overwriting the export object. So even if your code would worked, I guess all other exports would be destroyed (overwritten) by this. Thus maybe node has some protecting mechanism to avoid such a case